# Django ORM How I can get average value

Tags: sql, django, django-orm

## models.py

```
class Testimonials(models.Model):
    RATING = (
            (1,'Очень плохо'),
            (2,'Плохо'),
            (3,'Средне'),
            (4,'Хорошо'),
            (5,'Очень хорошо'),
        )
    EXP = (
            (1, 'Не указан'),
            (2, 'Один день'),
            (3, 'Одна неделя'),
            (4, 'Один месяц'),
            (5, 'Более года'),
        )
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    publish = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    testimonial = models.TextField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
    rating_sup = models.IntegerField(choices=RATING, max_length=1, null=True, blank=True)
    rating_stability = models.IntegerField(choices=RATING, max_length=1, null=True, blank=True)
    rating_trust = models.IntegerField(choices=RATING, max_length=1, null=True, blank=True)
    experience = models.IntegerField(choices=EXP, max_length=1, default=1, blank=True)
    affiliate = models.ForeignKey(Affiliate, null=True, blank=True)
    offer = models.ForeignKey(Offer, null=True, blank=True)
```

My queryset is:

```
Affiliate.objects.get(pk=2).testimonials_set.all().aggregate(Avg('rating_trust'), Avg('rating_sup'), Avg('rating_stability'))
```

Result:

```
{'rating_stability__avg': 3.0, 'rating_trust__avg': None, 'rating_sup__avg': 4.0}
```

How I can get average, of 3 values ((3+4)/2=3.5)

Comment: You mean, how to calculate it?

Comment: No, I need to get average of 3 different columns, and then sort by that value

Comment: if None should be ignored

Answer (score 2):

You must try with F() functions. I think this could solve your problem

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/queries/#f-expressions

```
Affiliate.objects.get(pk=2).testimonials_set.all().aggregate(Avg(F('rating_stability') + F('rating_sup')))
```

Comment: The problem here is that if if one of 'rating_stability' or 'rating_sup' is NULL, the sum will be NULL, which will give wrong results.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a `default=0` value to your model fields which you want to aggregate:

```
rating_sup = models.IntegerField(choices=RATING, max_length=1, blank=True, default=0)
rating_stability = models.IntegerField(choices=RATING, max_length=1, blank=True, default=0)
rating_trust = models.IntegerField(choices=RATING, max_length=1, blank=True, default=0)
```

and then you can aggregate all thre fields using `Avg`

```
Affiliate.testimonials_set.all().aggregate(avr=Avg(F('rating_trust') + F('rating_sup') + F('rating_stability'))).order_by('avr')
```

Comment: `Avg` takes only one positional argument. https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.9.2/django/db/models/aggregates.py#L76

Comment: it gives me TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (4 given)

Comment: I don't think setting default=0 prevents F('...') from being `None`. Does it?

Comment: @AntoinePinsard i think it should be `0`: as the docs say `An F() object represents the value of a model field...`

Comment: So if the value is NULL in the database, the F(...) expression should be evaluated as None. (I think)

Comment: It works, thank you. But avr returns 2.3, i need to get 3.5, None value should be ignored.

Comment: Just changed the model and set default=0 to rating columns and 
Affiliate.objects.get(pk=2).testimonials_set.all().aggregate(avr=Avg(F('rating_trust') + F('rating_sup') + F('rating_stability'))) returns None for me

Comment: @СавостьяновМаксим you have set `null=True` in those fields?

Comment: yes, if i set null=False, and try to add record in db i got error: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Comment: @СавостьяновМаксим remove `null=True` as in my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104658/discussion-between---and-doru).